# convert lat long coordinates in a table to MGRS

Tags: convert, mgrs

I have an Excel table with lat and long coordinates in separate fields. Now I'd like to convert these fields into a third field with its MGRS coordinate. Any suggestions of how?

Comment: If you have access to ArcGIS 10.x, there is a "Convert Coordinate Notation" tool that will do this. MGRS is a coded alphanumeric string based on UTM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have ArcGIS 10+, you can use the [convert Coordinate notation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000tw000000) tool, as mentioned by Neil Ayres.

If you don't have ArcGIS, you can use [EarthPoint batch converter](http://www.earthpoint.us/BatchConvert.aspx), which works directly from a spreadsheet.